# Why printing config array gives empty Array?

Tags: php, smarty

```
$tpl = new Smarty();
$tpl->configLoad('compose.conf');
$config = $tpl->getConfigVars();
print_r($config);
```

it returns

```
Array()
```

What is it, I am doing wrong?

compose.conf

```
[jquery]
jquery = lib/jquery/jquery.js

[jquery_validate]
css=res/css/jquery.validate.css
js=lib/jquery/jquery.validate.js
X=jquery


[bootstrap_css]
main = lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css
theme = lib/ootstrap-theme.min.css

[bootstrap_js]
js = lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js
X=jquery

[bootstrap]
X=bootstrap_css,bootstrap_js

[utils]
utils=lib/utils/utils.js
odo=lib/utils/utils.odo.js
require=libutils/utils.require.js
template=lib/utils/utils.template.js
X=jquery
```

Comment: What does `compose.conf` contain?

Comment: It contains config vars, see edit.

Comment: Is there anything in error logs? Maybe you mean to be calling `config_load` instead of `configLoad`?

Comment: `conpose.conf` is not the same as `compose.conf`, but that may just be a typo.

Comment: @h2ooooooo yes just typo

Comment: @mbanzon in Smarty 3, its configLoad instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your smarty plugins directory
smarty_internal_config.php
search for statment

```
if (!empty($sections)) {
```

now replace this statement with

```
    if($sections=='*'){
        foreach ($_config_vars['sections'] as $key=>$value) {
            if (isset($value['vars'])) {
                $scope_ptr->config_vars[$key] = $value['vars'];
            }
        }
    } else if (!empty($sections)) {
```

and while loading file use it like this

```
$tpl = new Smarty();
$tpl->configLoad('compose.conf','*');
$config = $tpl->getConfigVars();
print_r($config);
```

Thats it:)

Answer (score 1):

According to the manual of [parse_ini_file](http://www.php.net/parse_ini_file):

> **Note:** There are reserved words which must not be used as keys for ini files. These include: `null`, `yes`, `no`, `true`, `false`, >>> **`on`** <<<, `off`, `none`. Values `null`, `off`, `no` and `false` result in `""`. Values `on`, `yes` and `true` result in `"1"`. Characters `?{}|&~![()^"` must not be used anywhere in the key and have a special meaning in the value.

If we try to execute `parse_ini_file` (or `parse_ini_string`) on your file [we get the following error](https://eval.in/153099):

> **Warning:** syntax error, unexpected BOOL_TRUE in Unknown on line 7
>    in /tmp/execpad-e67cf6f095ae/source-e67cf6f095ae on line 32

Hence Smarty is getting an error (I'm assuming that it uses one of these functions internally) when trying to parse your INI file because you use a reserved word. The solution is to simply rename `ON` to something else.

**Update**:

Smarty doesn't use these functions, but its parser replicates it. Line #313 of `smarty_internal_configfilelexer.php` refers to `"on"`:

```
if (!$this->smarty->config_booleanize || !in_array(strtolower($this->value), Array("true", "false", "on", "off", "yes", "no")) ) {
//                                                                                                   ^^
```

Comment: @LNT There's still one left under `bootstrap_js`: `ON=jquery`